# Fetching Table Names from Oracle with Java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, resultset

I'm working on a Java GUI project; in one of its property screen I use 3 comboboxes in order to get: first user chooses DB name, with this value 2.Schema names and with this all table names under that schema. It's OK when I use ResultSet when getting the values from DB and setting them. But with this way, I could only bring ONE value because you know the way ResultSet works. So is there any other way that I could fetch all the table names with let's say:

`SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES;` and put them on an array of Strings or sth... Anything possible, I just wanna have their names in a list or anything.

Thank you.

EDIT:

Here's the simple code tested for the purpose:

```
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
String result;
ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES");

rs = ps.executeQuery(); 

while(rs.next())
{
        result = rs.getString(1);
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
```

Comment: We indeed know how ResultSet works, and thus know that it can contain multiple rows. Show us your code, so that we can fix it.

Comment: @JB Nizet: This is strange, considering the only way to get `ResultSet` to yield you **any** row is to call a method named `next()`. The word "next" would usually suggest more rows...

Comment: Err, yes. That's why I said that a resultset can contain several rows, and not just one as the OP says in his question. Did I miss something?

Comment: @JB Nizet: No, you didn't miss anything. I was just agreeing. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by 'you know the way resultset works'?! This will return all the rows from the query:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.print("Column 1 returned ");
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
```

Comment: well I ment that "specifying" the value like you said rs.getString(1) only returns the first row of the first column, right?

Comment: no, rs.getString(1) gets the value from column 1 of the current row. On the next iteration of the while loop, the current row will be ro2 2, then row 3 and so on..

Comment: yes that's fine but that only happens when I add rs.next() in the loop then print it out...How am I gonna do that?

Comment: how crazy was that; oh my how could I put the close statements in the loop... :) thank you StevieG anyways...

Answer (score 0):

You need to quesry for meta data basically. See this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/ListtheTablesinanSQLdatabase.htm) on how to do it.

Comment: thank you but in this way rs.getString(3) not only returns a weird value including numbers and characters but also throws a java.lang.NullPointerException... And also I don't want to get just 1 table name like specifying sth rs.getString(3); I want to fetch all of them into an array or sth. How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a List:

```
List<String> tableNames = new ArrayList<String>();
while(rs.next()) {
    String tableName = rs.getString(1);
    tableNames.add(tableName);
}
// there: your list contains all the table names
```

Read the [tutorial about collections](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/). This is stuff that all Java developers must know.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
DatabaseMetaData  metadata = currentConnection.getMetaData();
String[] names = {"TABLE"}; 
ResultSet tables = metadata.getTables(null,"%", "%", names);
while (tables.next()) { 
  String tableName = tables.getString("TABLE_NAME"); 
  String tableSchema = tables.getString("TABLE_SCHEM");
}
```

Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDatabaseMetaData.html#getTables_java_lang_String__java_lang_String__java_lang_String__java_lang_String___) for more info.